# Change Input[type=range] thumb styles with Jquery - Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a range slider that showcases different banner sizes visually. I'm trying to create a function that allows the input-range-thumb to change it's background color when a .mousedown and a .mouseup event is triggered. I read that there is no way to select the thumb directly using simple Jquery. I read that creating a class, and using an .AddClass method is best.

I've attempted this myself, and i can't seem to figure out why the thumb will not change colors.

Could you look at my code?

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/LWomev

```
    //1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Thumb the thumbs background-color will change to blue.
$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() {
    $(this).addClass("thumb-down");
});
//2. When user mouse up on the Range-Thumb the Thumbs background-color will change to Green.
$("#range-slider").on("mouseup", function() {
    $(this).addClass("thumb-up");
});
```

***The Problem was Solved! Here is the fixed version*** https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/OpKKMd

```js
var imageUrl = new Array(); 

        imageUrl[0] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg';

        imageUrl[1] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1AQ.svg';

        imageUrl[2] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Bb.svg';

        imageUrl[3] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Am.svg';

        imageUrl[4] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1CG.svg';

        imageUrl[5] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1By.svg';
       
$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});


// ::::: Range Slider Thumb ::::: //

//1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Slider
$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() {
  //1.1 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .thumb-down (changes background color)
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("thumb-down");
  //1.2 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .hover-ring (changes box-shadow to a green color)
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("hover-ring");
});
//2. When user mouse up on the Range-Slider the Thumbs background-color will change to Green
$("#range-slider").on("mouseup", function() {
  //2.1 Add class .thumb-up
    $(this).addClass("thumb-up");
    $(this).addClass("hover-ring-out");
});
```

```css
.product-range-wrapper {
  displat: -webkit-flex;
  displat:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  /*outline: 1px solid purple;*/
 }
.product-range-block {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
.ref-height-block {
  flex-grow:3;
  /*background-color:red;*/
}
.size-chart-block {
  flex-grow:9;
  /*background-color:green;*/
}
.product-range-block img {
  width:90%;
  /*outline: 1px solid blue;*/
}
#img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
#slider_count {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:200px;
  padding:20px 20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:yellow;
}

/* ::::::::::::::::::::Range Slider Styles::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
.range-slider-block {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:90%;
  }
#range-slider {
  padding:40px 0px;
  width:100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid green;*/
}
/* Remove Range Sliders Default Styles*/
input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/* Track */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
/* Thumb */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #46947F;
    margin-top: -9px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6pt rgba(190,190,190,0.4);
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* JS Stykes */
/* Changes Thumb color to darker green when mousedownn */
input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#316557;
}
/* Changes Thumb color back to light green when mouseup */
input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#46947F;  
}
/* Changes Ring color Green */
input[type=range].hover-ring::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6pt rgba(70,148,127,0.46);
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=range].hover-ring-out::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-range-wrapper">
  
  <div class="product-range-block">
    <div class="ref-height-block">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/1Ba.svg" alt="Product Height Refrence" height="" width="">
    </div>
    <div class="size-chart-block">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg" style='' id='img'/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="range-slider-block">
    <input type="range" id="range-slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
  </div>
  
  
</div>




<div id="slider_count">slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a css problem you have. in the class background color definition i set it important and it runs

```
#range-slider {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.thumb-down {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.thumb-up {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

have a look on this working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/w363w6ke/1/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using !important unless there is absolutely no other way

Comment: `$("#range-slider").on('mousedown', function(){$('#range-slider').css('background-color', 'red');});` is an option for you?

Comment: You can do this without using inline styles too

Comment: Thanks so much. If you have any advice why the imageUrl[0] is not showing by default on page load would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Like TypedSource said, it's a CSS problem. You just have to be more specific in your selector in order to get your styles to override the previous background color.

You can do it like this:

```
input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:blue;
}
input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:green;  
}
```

Comment: So far this is the best solution without changing my code much. :)

//1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Thumb the thumbs background-color will change to blue.
$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("thumb-down");
});

Adding the .removeClass{}. allows it to reset.

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/LWomev

Comment: You might also need to alter your js toggle so that both classes don't exist on the same element at the same time. Need to use removeClass for this

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the imageUrl[0] does not show by default on page-load?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the :active pseudo selector to change to blue.  You don't even need mouse events.

```js
var imageUrl = new Array(); 

        imageUrl[0] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg';

        imageUrl[1] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1AQ.svg';

        imageUrl[2] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Bb.svg';

        imageUrl[3] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Am.svg';

        imageUrl[4] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1CG.svg';

        imageUrl[5] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1By.svg';
       
$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});
```

```css
.product-range-wrapper {
  displat: -webkit-flex;
  displat:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  /*outline: 1px solid purple;*/
 }
.product-range-block {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
.ref-height-block {
  flex-grow:3;
  /*background-color:red;*/
}
.size-chart-block {
  flex-grow:9;
  /*background-color:green;*/
}
.product-range-block img {
  width:90%;
  /*outline: 1px solid blue;*/
}
#img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
#slider_count {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:200px;
  padding:20px 20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:yellow;
}
/*#range-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(100% - (0px));
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d7dcdf;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}*/

/* ::::::::::::::::::::Range Slider Styles::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
.range-slider-block {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:90%;
  }
#range-slider {
  padding:40px 0px;
  width:100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid green;*/
}
/* Remove Range Sliders Default Styles*/
input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/* Track */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
/*input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}*/
/* Thumb */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #46947F;
    margin-top: -9px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4pt #BEBEBE;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background:blue;  
}

/*input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background:#ffffff;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-range-wrapper">
  
  <div class="product-range-block">
    <div class="ref-height-block">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/1Ba.svg" alt="Product Height Refrence" height="" width="">
    </div>
    <div class="size-chart-block">
      <img src="" style='' id='img'/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="range-slider-block">
    <input type="range" id="range-slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
  </div>
  
  
</div>




<div id="slider_count">slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span></div>
```

Comment: I think this just changes the Range-sliders track background-color. I'm trying to target the "slider-thumb" the piece you click on, and drag to select the slider value.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  If your goal is simply to change the color of the handle when the use has it pressed, you don't need mouse events, you can simply use the :active pseudo selector.  I've altered the code above to reflect this.  It's much less code and only 1 line in your css as opposed to the additional classes.

Comment: Thanks! Would this be easier than..?

input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:blue;
}
input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:green;  
}

Comment: yes, its much simpler because you don't need to use javascript or jquery to add and remove classes.  It's a pure CSS solution.  You have your normal state which is green... and you have your :active state which is blue (see the code snippet in this answer) and notice the javascript is no longer there, and all i've added is the new selector with with the `:active` pseudo selector

Comment: That's genius. :) I'm about to post this second question, but i figured i would ask. Do you know why image[0] is not showing on page-load by default? The slider loads with a blank image, and only shows image[0] once the user moves the range-slider-thumb.

Comment: your image doesn't have a src attribute populated when the page loads.  It's empty. `src=""`.  You're only populating it with javascript after events take place.

Comment: Thanks. That now seems obvious. ha

Comment: This is the best solution